# How to parse and loads JSON in bash shell script?

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, api

I am trying to loads and print JSON response in shell script.I dont have any idea how to achieve this.Please help me on this.

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

malop_q=$(curl -X GET -k -H "SEC: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 'https://127.0.0.1/api/reference_data/sets/malopid?fields=data(value)')

echo $malop_q
```

JSON Response:

```
{"data":[{"value":"11.945403842773683082"},{"value":"11.945403842773683082"},{"value":"11.945403842773683082"}]}
```

Expected OP is

I need to print values from above JSON response is:

```
11.945403842773683082
11.945403842773683082
11.945403842773683082
```

Thanks in advance.

'

Comment: Are you looking for "bash only" answer? or answer which uses python?

Comment: Have a look at [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Using text processing tools (like `awk`) for parsing `json` is never the best idea. Use a tool that has `json` parsing libraries.

Comment: Yes, I required bash only

Answer (score 2):

The following python code do the parsing, assuming that you save it as: my_json.py

```
import json,sys

obj=json.load(sys.stdin)
for i in range(len(obj['data'])):
    print obj['data'][i]['value']
```

You can get the respond using:

```
malop_q=$(curl -X GET -k -H "SEC: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 'https://127.0.0.1/api/reference_data/sets/malopid?fields=data(value)')   
echo $malop_q | python my_json.py
```

or in one line:

```
curl -X GET -k -H "SEC: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 'https://127.0.0.1/api/reference_data/sets/malopid?fields=data(value)' | python my_json.py
```

Answer (score 2):

With Python :

```
import json

with open('file.json') as json_file:    
    datas = json.load(json_file)

for d in datas["data"]:
  print(d["value"])
```